permission denied on database "test" when trying to create a schema in GCP Cloud SQL for Postgres
Background Info
I have a GCP project called abc-stage which hosts all the deployments for my dev and test targets, along with the required resources. All applications are deployed to Cloud Run, and they use Cloud SQL for Postgres 15.
I have two databases in the Cloud SQL instance (let's call the instance csql) - dev and test. All of my cloud run applications have their own schema in the respective database. So for the following CR applications - svc1, svc2, svc3 - I have the following schemas under both the dev and test databases - svc1, svc2 and svc3.
I also try to isolate permissions for these schemas by creating a new Cloud SQL user for each service. So the user list looks something like this:

dev_svc1_user
test_svc1_user
dev_scv2_user and so on

The creation of the databases is handled by a "shared" terraform config. The creation of the cloud sql users and the cloud run service is handled by the application-specific terraform config. They all use the same config, with just a few values changed.
The applications themselves are created with node and express. The schema creation, the granting of permissions for the user to the schema, and creation of tables along with granting permissions for the tables is handled in the express application with the node-pg-migrate library.
This setup has worked perfectly fine for all of my services so far. I created a new service a few days back and it worked as expected in the dev target. When deploying to the test target though, I get the following error:
Error executing:
CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS "svc4"
error: permission denied for database test

Fixes I have tried
I have tried doing a couple of things:

Running GRANT CONNECT ON database test to test_svc4_user;
Running GRANT CREATE ON database test to test_svc4_user;
Running GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON database test to test_svc4_user;
I executed all of these queries as the postgres user, as well as the other created users (test_svc1_user, test_svc2_user, etc.) with no luck.

Any idea on what I might be doing wrong, or what might be causing this issue?
